# ansible jinja2 template delimiters failed if using 'when'

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have this code, where the first task fails and the second task produces the following warning:
`[WARNING]: conditional statements should not include jinja2 templating delimiters such as {{ }} or {% %}. Found: {{ VRF }} == 17`

I am assuming this warning and the failure of the first task are happening for the same reason. From what I understand, the variables are different types. How do I fix this?

```
---
- name: PE_CE
  hosts: localhost

  tasks:

  - include_vars: /opt/netsec/ansible/orchestration/capabilities/PE_CE/PE_CE_1.yml
  
  - name: Build PE config Cisco
    template:
      src=/opt/netsec/ansible/orchestration/cisco_templates/PE_CE_CISCO_config_PE.j2
      dest=/opt/netsec/ansible/orchestration/config_outputs/new/{{PE_HOSTNAME}}
    when: "{{ PX_HOSTNAME }} == None"

  - name: Build CE config Cisco
    template:
      src=/opt/netsec/ansible/orchestration/cisco_templates/PE_CE_CISCO_config_CE.j2
      dest=/opt/netsec/ansible/orchestration/config_outputs/new/{{CE_HOSTNAME}}
    when: "{{ VRF }} == 17"
```

What I really want to do is `when: "{{ VRF }} == 17" and "{{ PX_HOSTNAME }} == None"`, or something like `{{ PX_HOSTNAME }}|length < 1"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need `{{` and `}}` with `when`. Do it like this:
`when: PX_HOSTNAME == "None"` and `when: VRF == "17"`

Here is some [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-strings)

`when: PX_HOSTNAME == "None"` will check if `PX_HOSTNAME` contains the string "None".
If you want to run the task if it is empty, do `when: not PX_HOSTNAME` or if you want to run the task it it is *not* empty, do `when: PX_HOSTNAME`.

You can use the length as well: `when: PX_HOSTNAME|length > 0`